# Retrieve json form api with basic authentication python

Tags: python, json, basic-authentication

Hello I'm making a python script for geektool to monitor my incoming mobile messages.
I've succeed to make it in java but i've never used python.

```
api url: https://mobilevikings.com/api/2.0/basic/usage.json
password: xxxx
username: yyyy
```

i already have the following non-working code, copy pasted from the internet

```
import urllib2, base64
request = urllib2.Request(url)
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

How do i receive the json file from the api?

Comment: For `urllib2` the code *should* just work. Have you tried the (far easier to use) [`requests` library](http://python-requests.org) yet? Its a separate install, but then you can just use `resp = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))`, then `result = resp.json()`.

Comment: The additional advantage of using `requests` is that there are add-on libraries like [`rauth`](https://rauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) that make using OAuth easy to use with it. I see mobilevikings.com gives you the option to use either, but recommends you use OAuth over Basic Authentication.

Comment: Why do you say that the code is non-working? What is the problem with it? Does it raise an exception, display error message, do nothing?

Comment: Did you try to search on `https://mobilevikings.com/api/` information about Python wrapper ? Maybe they created some useful tools in Python. It seems you didn't because you would see `python OAuth client` on that page.